# Use a CURL POST request with Java to upload image in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, curl, google-api, request, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload a file in a bucket on my Google Cloud Storage using Java. Due to my project's restriction, I muse use cURL. Google's docs provided this template of a cURL upload command:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @OBJECT_LOCATION \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: OBJECT_CONTENT_TYPE" \
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=OBJECT_NAME"
```

I tried this :

```
String tokenAuth = "TOKEN_HERE";
String filePth= "C:/DL API/vecteezy_isolated-tree-high-res_17219851_371.png";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
            "curl",
            "-X POST",
            "-data-binary "+filePth+" ",
            "-H \"Authorization: Bearer "+tokenAuth+"\"",
            "-H \"Content-Type: image/png\"",
"https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?uploadType=media&name=test.png");

    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    try{
        Process p = pb.start();
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
         String line;
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    System.out.println("youp "+bis);

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("ERROR" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

I used a buffer reader to get the content of the cURL output:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Bearer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: TOKEN HERE
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: image
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   124  100    54  100    70    201    260 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   464
<html><title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</title></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your usage of `ProcessBuilder`. Everything with a space between it (except for quoted strings) is a separate argument. "-X POST" is two arguments, not one. You also don't need to escape quotes. You're not using a shell. For example, this is wrong:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl",
    "-X POST",  // Should've been two strings, "-X" and "POST"
    "-H \"Foo: Bar\"");  // Likewise, should be "-H" and "Foo: Bar".
```

Try something more like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl",
        "-X", "POST",
        "-data-binary", filePath,
        "-H", "Authorization: Bearer "+tokenAuth,
        "-H", "Content-Type: image/png",
        "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o?"+
            "uploadType=media&name=test.png");
```

Also, you'll find it easier to read the logs and debug your use of cURL if you disable the progress bar updates (that's the "-s" flag) and also turn on verbose logging so you can see the request and make sure it's correct (that's the "-v" flag).